# Turn off specific USB port programmatically

Tags: java, windows-7, usb

I use an hardware device that goes in standby after it is not used for several minutes.
The only way to reactivate it is to unplug it from the USB port and reconnect it.
So I would like to know if there is a way to turn off (and then turn on) that specific USB port.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And you want to perform such a low level task in Java?

Comment: Any solution is accepted :)

Comment: I am also looking for an answer as struggling with the same problem.